# CSRF implementation in a MERN stack

Tags: node.js, csrf, reactjs

Below is the file structure of my MERN project.

```
|-Project
  |- client
  |- server
```

Client folder contains a react server. 
Client runs at `localhost.client.com`
Server folder contains a code for the node.js server. 
Server runs at `localhost.server.com`

Whenever I'm making a request from the client to server. How can I mitigate the csrf attack? 
To make sure that the request made to the server is from the client and not from any other source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue might be covered in [React frontend and REST API, CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925344/react-frontend-and-rest-api-csrf).

There is an excellent article about [CSRF and counter measures](https://stormpath.com/blog/angular-xsrf) (with Angular in mind, but it is still the same problem). TL/DR:

- use [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) or set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`-header when needed
- save `XSRF-Token` as secure cookie (unfortunately this requires an exta request - most times). Only code from your domain can access this value.
- send that token as `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header value with your request to authorize the request

---

To make sure only your application can use the server api you can set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value in the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) / OPTIONS response header.

During development it usually is set to
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

for production you specify your domain / server name
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost.client.com`

To prevent spoofing the origin, you can use (Anti-)CSRF-Tokens. This are extra values attached to your request, which authenticate your request.
This value can/should be saved in a secure cookie. [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) or [JSON Web Tokens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) might be relevant for you. In your case CSRF-Tokens might require an extra request to your api to query the token.

Comment: but the domain name can be easily changed right. It won't be a perfect solution to mitigate csrf attack

Comment: correct, CSRF-Tokens might be a better solution. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work