# Is Firebase Auth's local (persisted auth state) secure and safe from XSS and CSRF for browsers?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, xss, csrf

I am using Firebase Auth for a web app that involves financial transactions. Thus, security is the most important thing for my app. According to [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence), Firebase can persist its token across multiple sessions by storing it somewhere. It does not mention how safe it is from XSS. Of course, I can just assume it's safe because it's Google, but I want to know more about it.

We've all read articles noting how localStorage is unsafe for storing auth, and cookie + csrf token + jwt + httpOnly is more secure way to handle auth for browsers.

How does Firebase store its token?
Does it use localStorage or cookie, or combination of both?

Comment: I've noticed when you use a private browser, the user info and the tokens are stored in a secure cookie, not the indexed DB.

Answer (score 7):

Firestore save the token in an Indexed DB (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). The DB is named "firebaseLocalStorageDb", the object store is named "firebaseLocalStorage", and the key firebase:authUser:[id].

For further code review, check out https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/authuser.js .

Comment: On the security side, I think there is a lot of debate on cookie vs. local storage. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133536/is-it-safe-to-store-a-jwt-in-localstorage-with-reactjs), so it's probably not simple/clear cut to call it secure or not.

Comment: and another good one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067251/where-to-store-jwt-in-browser-how-to-protect-against-csrf?rq=1