# Alternatives to JWT in localStorage for auto-Login in a react SPA?

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, nginx, jwt

i've read lately that storing JWT tokens in the localStorage is considered a bad practice, you can easily implement set-cookie headers on the server side with httpOnly flag, to prevent XSS, but with it, the client side javascript has no knowledge of previous actions by the User (like a succesful Login), how is it possible to implement Auto-Login feature without the use of localStorage? bind the JWT token to a specific IP-address?

We have an NGINX server over https, which serves the static React SPA files, and also talks with the express backend.
i'm really clueless with this.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a duplicate of [Where to store JWT in browser? How to protect against CSRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067251/where-to-store-jwt-in-browser-how-to-protect-against-csrf)

mentioning react / autologin doesnt make a difference on the core problem