# Where do i need to start if I want my Spring/React app to remember my login info when opening a new tab?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, jwt, single-sign-on

I have a web app which is secured with JWT. How to make it remember my login data and not to enter it all again if I open a new tab? I use axios.post to the authenticate endpoint and save the token in localStorage
My code of the authentication service in frontend:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/map-runner'

export const USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'authenticatedUser'

class AuthenticationService {

    executeJwtAuthenticationService(username, password) {
        return axios.post(`${API_URL}/authenticate`, {
            username,
            password
        })
    }

    registerSuccessfulLoginForJwt(username, token) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username)
        localStorage.setItem("token", token)
    }

    createJWTToken(token) {
        return 'Bearer ' + token
    }


    logout() {
        sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    }

    isUserLoggedIn() {
        let user = sessionStorage.getItem(USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
        if (user === null) return false
        return true
    }

    getLoggedInUserName() {
        let user = sessionStorage.getItem(USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
        if (user === null) return ''
        return user
    }

    setupAxiosInterceptors(token) {
        axios.interceptors.request.use(
            (config) => {
                if (this.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                    config.headers.authorization = token
                }
                return config
            }
        )
    }
}

export default new AuthenticationService()
```

Now my Login Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AuthenticationService from '../service/AuthenticationService';

class LoginComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            hasLoginFailed: false,
            showSuccessMessage: false
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState(
            {
                [event.target.name]
                    : event.target.value
            }
        )
    }

    loginClicked = () => {
        AuthenticationService
            .executeJwtAuthenticationService(this.state.username, this.state.password)
            .then((response) => {
                AuthenticationService.registerSuccessfulLoginForJwt(this.state.username, response.data.token)
                console.log(response.data.token);
                this.props.history.push(`/calculations`)
            }).catch(() => {
                this.setState({ showSuccessMessage: false })
                this.setState({ hasLoginFailed: true })
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Вход</h1>
                <div className="container">
                    {this.state.hasLoginFailed && <div className="alert alert-warning">Неверные данные</div>}
                    {this.state.showSuccessMessage && <div>Вход выполнен успешно</div>}
                    Имя пользователя: <input type="text" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    Пароль: <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.loginClicked}>Вход</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginComponent
```

The backend in spring boot is quite long even regarding the JWT part, so I guess I'll leave the link to the tutorial which was the basis of my backend. The paths are a bit different but in general these backend parts are the same.. I also tried to use sessionstorage instead of localstorage, doesnt work. If possible, maybe we can test everything out firstly replicating the whole tutorial code as the jwt part is almost the same there (I have a copy and they have a link to their github in the article)

Comment: just retrieve the token from the localstorage and put it in your post, then in backend check if you are already logged and if is still valid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to store JWT in browser? How to protect against CSRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067251/where-to-store-jwt-in-browser-how-to-protect-against-csrf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be having login page where you would be sending jwt token at the time of login so
store the jwt token at the time if login as

```
 axios.post("http:yourAPIaddresshere", formData)
    .then((response) => {
       if(response.status === 200) {
          // storing session 
          localStorage.setItem('session', response.data.token)
          this.props.history.push('home');
        } else {
          this.showMessage('Error message', "Please check your credentials.")
        }
      } 
    });
}
```

This is where your session is stored in localStorage now in other all the files retrieve the token
In same login file also do :

```
 componentDidMount(){
       if (localStorage.getItem('session') !== null) {
         this.props.history.push('home')
       }
     }
```

this will always push your navigation to other tabs.
To make your other tabs/pages secure also check session if not null it won't let you open other pages using routes without session token

```
 componentDidMount(){
       if (localStorage.getItem('session') === null)
     this.props.history.push('login') }
```

P.S: Make sure to empty the sesion token at the time of logout as :

```
 localStorage.removeItem('session');
```

Comment: Thank You! I use sessionless in backend config

Comment: Mark as answer if this helped you, Thank You :)

Comment: Thank you, but for now it still isn't working... Maybe I should upload some code here somewhere?

Comment: I edited, and added the link from where I took the backend

Comment: did you try using localStorage ?

Comment: I did... look in the first code part localStorage.setItem("token", token)

Comment: logout() {
        sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    }

    isUserLoggedIn() {
        let user = sessionStorage.getItem(USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
        if (user === null) return false
        return true
    } You should use token here to check instead of USER_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME

Answer (score 1):

You can save the token either in local storage or cookie. And every-time you send any xhr request you can pass the token in the header.