# if I store access token (JWT) in my local storage of angular project what is wrong in it?

Tags: angular, angular8

if I store token in my local storage of angular project what is wrong in it. Apart from this, what is the other way to store token in my project because I am using client-side framework so everything is open to see if I use local/session storage, indexedDB, cookies

Answer (score 0):

Cross Site Request Forgery(CSRF) is a pertinent problem when you store the token in localStorage. Do not store JWT in the local storage. Refer to this link for more details [Where to store JWT in browser? How to protect against CSRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067251/where-to-store-jwt-in-browser-how-to-protect-against-csrf)