# how to keep the user logged, in an http-only cookie?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, session

I understand the http-only cookie cant be accessed from the js  **how could i keep an user logged, in a react app?**. *should I set an endpoint   on the backend and just   send  requests  there to check if the user cookie stills there?* which is the best way to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get HTTP-only cookie in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970499/how-to-get-http-only-cookie-in-react)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.