# ReactJS and access tokens

Tags: reactjs, security, access-token, httponly

I want to store my refresh token in react, but I'm not sure where to store it. I've heard that it's best to store it in "HttpOnly" cookies. But I know it's not possible.

I saw online to store it in the local storage, but I know it's a bad idea. I also saw that I should store in context, then other opinions sparked saying that it's wrong to do so, I really don't know what to do.

So many opinions.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: why is HttpOnly not possible for you?

Comment: @Quak_2023 according to this post, it's not possible since you are using JS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970499/how-to-get-http-only-cookie-in-react

Comment: What i meant is for a refresh token why cant you store it in a http only cookie and have the server handle it? and that question handles the actual token not the refresh token