# Can I store jwt token in local storage while using Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We want to use Next.js for our application but we would be using mainly client side rendering for fetching data. The API is an external API will built that we would be calling. Only the homepage will be using server side rendering.

The core API would require login to access the dashboard and the dashboard content is user specific. So, we want to use client side data fetching in next.js.

JWT was used in the external API to give user's authorization and user's role along with other user's details were stored in the JWT access token. We are new to Nextjs and wanted to know how to go about with this.
We need each user to send their access token as part of their request when making API request while inside the dashboard.

Can we store this access token in their local storage and pass it to their header bearer while making API requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. After the request is made to login, and the API returns the JWT, you can call localstorage to [set the item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem). Then when making the client side request you would call localstorage to [get the item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), then pass it in the headers of the request. Keep in mind, you will need to manage expiration.

Another way to go about this is when logging in, have the API return a header for [setting a cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) which stores the JWT in cookies. Then when making the request (granted on the same host) it will automatically pass along the cookie if you set the header [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)

Personally, I would go with Cookies, because if they are set them to HTTP-Only it will [increase security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63407248/3530423). It also comes with the benefit of having an expiration time so the cookie will clear when it is no longer valid, and the user can close the page, and reopen and still be logged in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I implement refresh token system with this cookie method?

Comment: @kingNodejs yes, you would also need to set-cookie the refresh token, then handle the refreshing on the api. Basically, if the auth token is invalid, but the refresh token is valid, generate new token and send back the response with set-cookie and the new token. This article might help you wrap your head around using cookies to manage them (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens/)

Comment: @kingNodejs And if I put jwt token in the localStorage, how to send it on page refresh so that I can grab data based on jwt in server component and initialize redux store let's say?

Answer (score 0):

[Yes you can but Do not store token inside local storage !!](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/security-guidance/data-security/token-storage#don-t-store-tokens-in-local-storage)

> Auth0 recommends storing tokens in browser memory as the most secure option.

To achieve this : use either a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to send the token to your code when needed or just store the token in memory. For example, when you receive your token, put it in a variable accessible to your application.

This way you prevent yourself from [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) because local storage can be accessed by any script downloaded by the end user.

> Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks are a type of injection, in which malicious scripts are injected [...]

Finally, I can recommend to simply store your token inside an **http-only** cookie : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie easiest by far

Comment: I think I will take the http-only approach. If I am going to use http-only can it be stored there? There wont be any more need to store it anywhere, right?

Comment: yes exactly. Don't forget to make it not only http-only but also "same-site" to prevent CSRF https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store JWT tokens in local storage while using Next.js for client-side rendering. Storing the token in local storage is a common approach for managing authentication tokens in client-side applications.

**Authentication Flow:** Implement a login flow where users can authenticate with your external API and receive a JWT token upon successful authentication.

**Storing the Token:** After receiving the JWT token from the API, store it in the local storage of the browser. You can do this using the localStorage API provided by the browser.

```
localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token);
```

**Retrieving the Token:** Whenever you need to make an API request that requires authentication, retrieve the token from local storage.

```
const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
```

**Passing the Token in API Requests:** Include the token in the header of your API requests, typically as a Bearer token.

```
fetch('https://example/api/dashboard-data', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```