# How can I implement JWT authentication while navigating between pages?

Tags: authentication, jwt

This seems like it should have an obvious workflow, but everything I've tried so far has introduced problems. I've got a Go server with JWT authentication set up. I would like to call that authentication to permit access to various endpoints. I've discussed at length with chatGPT how to handle this, and the solution it's provided hasn't worked. I've tried googling how it's supposed to work, but I don't have enough knowledge of the individual parts to ask the right questions. The best I can tell, going to a given URL in a browser doesn't give any opportunity to include a header, so simple navigation can't include the token. ChatGPT's solution is to use

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
fetch(authCurrentURL, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${JWT}`
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.ok) {
                            return response.text(); // Get the HTML content as text
                        } else {
                            // Authentication failed, handle the error or redirect if needed.
                            sessionStorage.removeItem('DaypassToken');
                            localStorage.removeItem('NPCTavernToken');
                            throw new Error('Authentication failed');
                        }
                    })
                    .then(htmlContent => {
                        // Replace the current page's content with the authenticated HTML content
                        document.body.innerHTML = htmlContent;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        // Handle network errors or authentication failures.
                        console.log(error)
                    });
}
```

but when I load content using document.body.innerHTML = htmlContent, none of the scripts run. Not even very simple lines like console.log().

I'm not set on doing it this way; if there's a better workflow for submitting the POST request with the authorization header, I'm all ears. If this is the standard work flow, what am I doing wrong that the page is basically non-functional?

Comment: "*I've discussed at length with chatGPT how to handle this, and the solution it's provided hasn't worked*" "*ChatGPT's solution*" ChatGPT is a large language model, and not a serious programming tool - it shouldn't be used as such. It often fails to accomplish even basic programming tasks and is known to generate buggy, vulnerable, or (as you encountered) outright non-working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The best I can tell, going to a given URL in a browser doesn't give any opportunity to include a header, so simple navigation can't include the token [...]

Why do you necessarily need to pass it in a header? [RFC 7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519) doesn't prescribe this (or any method, actually) as the only valid way to pass the token itself to the server.

In your specific situation, what you might be able to take advantage of is storing it in a cookie, which browsers transmit to matching origins by default on every request the client makes. Your Go server could verify it before sending a response. Just be sure [to protect against CSRF attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067251/where-to-store-jwt-in-browser-how-to-protect-against-csrf) as you normally would.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this entire branch of programming. I saw something that suggested cookies were pretty sub-optimal for dealing with JWTs, and have been trying to figure out the intended work flow. Is header-authorization more of an application level approach then?

Comment: Transmitting the JWT in the `Authorization` header is somewhat of a *de facto* standard, but it lends itself way better to applications where the front end is affirmatively decoupled from the backend (i.e., your backend isn't generating HTML for every request) which seems to not be the case for you here. "*I saw something that suggested cookies were pretty sub-optimal for dealing with JWTs*" Can you cite this assertion? Not saying it's necessarily wrong, but I'd be curious to understand contextually what the author is trying to convey and why they believe this.

Comment: A side benefit of the decoupled front/back-end design and using JWTs in the way you describe (aside from sidestepping cross-origin concerns raised specifically with a cookie-based pattern) is that you can use the same approach to allow external applications to consume data from your APIs (in an environment outside a browser where it's not exactly standard to have to deal with cookies) without needing to reinvent the wheel for it.

Comment: Actually, I think the right design for my project wouldn't be generating HTML for every request, I just don't know what I'm doing. When the only tool you've got is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.

Ultimately, you've answered my question. The right way to authenticate the user with a single call is cookies. If I can break my data out from my HTML construction, maybe then I could get away with fetch-centric authentication.

I don't remember for sure where I picked up the idea that I should avoid cookies. It might even have been one of the discussions on that CSRF protections page.