JWT in HttpOnlyCookie problem with third party block
I have been (for quite a long time) developing apps using Angular for the frontend and PHP for the backend. I handled the security creating a JWT token that was sent from the back to the front and then stored in localStorage to keep the user logged in even if the browser was closed.
But recently I read that storing the token on localStorage was a terrible idea! Mainly because is accesible to anyone that sits on the same computer and can be read using Javascript. So I read that the proper way to go is to store it on a HttpOnly Secure cookie and send it on every API call. I changed that and made an interceptor to send it "WithCredentials".
But the problem is the architecture of my apps. I usually develop them on a subdomain (https://app.example.com) and have the backend on another subdomain (https://api.example.com). So, the backend sets a HttpOnly Secure cookie... and is blocked because of the third-party blocking default policy on browsers nowadays...
How should I approach this? I have tried discussing it with ChatGPT, Gemini, Claude... and it was useless...
Thanks!

recently I read...where? Quote your sources, please. can be read using Javascript...but only from the same origin, not by scripts from other domains. Of course if your site has XSS vulnerabilities then that could still be an issue - but then the solution to that is to fix the vulnerabilities.

anyone that sits on the same computer...only if they use the same login as the person who ran the app and created the token. And if that happens, it's the original user's fault for sharing their account with someone else.

I have tried discussing it with ChatGPT, Gemini, Claude... and it was useless...well they are not programmers, so that should not be a big surprise.

@ADyson Shared computers are still a thing - think about a small retail business that might have a single computer for EPOS on their counter shared by multiple people. Eventually someone is going to need to open a web-browser and login to something - and it's very easy to forget to explicitly log-out of anything. Or people using computers in a public library that just can't get any IT people in). So I'll contradict you and say that it's not users' own fault; we design those systems, so we share responsibility for not making applications secure in a shared-computer environment.

@Dai Well maybe. But if you store your token anywhere on the client side, in cookies or anything else then its potentially accessible by anyone using that device, if they share the same login. Cookies are visible in the browser tools too. So that by itself isn't an argument for not using localstorage. If people want to log into something private then they either should use their own personal phone or other device, or be disciplined about logging out after their session.

@Dai ...About all you can do as a developer to mitigate against those kinds of lax security behaviours is have very short token lifetimes and/or use multi-factor authentication

I read it to several developers I follow on X, Medium or web.dev (even here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067251/where-to-store-jwt-in-browser-how-to-protect-against-csrf). Even on a big tech, if someone leaves the computer unlocked I can open the devtools and copy de localStorage saved token on 30 secs and create it on my computer, if it's on a cookie at least it would be more difficult to replicate it. I agree, AI chatbots are not programmers, but help programming, and that's why I'm here after asking them.

But after all these comments, the key point of my question remains unanswered. What strategy should I follow if my front and back are on different domains? Should I drop using cookies and keep using localStorage? Any "secure" strategy I should follow if I keep using it? After leaving uni we are on a job that makes us always "self-taught" students, and as such, I keep trying to improve my working methods and my code. Thanks for the quick responses :)

if it's on a cookie at least it would be more difficult to replicate it...why? What stops you copying that too from the dev tools? I'm not seeing the difference

You are right in that Local Storage is an unsafe place to store a cookie. You can see my answer on a similar question here.
You are also right in that more and more browsers choose to block third party cookies, it's probably just a matter of time before all of them do by default. See here for Chrome.
Cookies coming from app.example.com can be sent to api.example.com, but you have to specify that in your backend when you create the cookie, see the RFC. I think that the leading dot is no longer needed (see here), but you should be able to enforce this by testing to specify Set-Cookie: Path=/; Domain=.example.com
Are you 100% sure that your cookie is not sent to api.example.com? It's not that you are having CORS problems or similar? Try and capture the traffic in your Inspector tool, and look for the cookie header in the request.
